# Stone-Čech Compactification of The integers is $T_5$?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Since $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is $T_2$ and compact we can conclude that it is $T_4$. However, what about $T_5$? My only guess will be that $\beta\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{N}$ is not normal. Is this true?

Comment: Isn't $\beta\mathbb N-\mathbb N$ a closed subset of $\beta\mathbb N$?

Comment: $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is indeed not $T_5$ but not for that reason..

Comment: N is discrete, hence locally compact, hence the remainder in any compactification of N is closed, hence normal. But \beta N  has some non-normal subpaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as all points of $\mathbb{N}$ are isolated ,it's an open subset of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ (in general any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ will be open in $\beta X$). So its remainder $\beta\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is a closed subset of $\beta \mathbb{N}$ hence compact + $T_2$ thus normal.

[this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1025.8642&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  has a construction of non-normal subspaces.

Comment: But, is $\beta\mathbb{N}$ a $T_5$ space?

Comment: @Luke No it's not. But the proof will depend on how much you know about this space.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this discussion? or more properties of this space? I'm restricted to its definition using ultrafilters over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Luke I added a reference.

Comment: An example is given in General Topolgy by R. Engelking of a non-normal subspace of $\beta N$.... Chapter 3, parts 3.6.18 & 3.6.19. You might want to review Section 3.5 and also 3.6.1 thru 3.6. 17 first.

Answer (score 1):

Streamlined version of the example in the reference that I gave in a comment:

(1). Let $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb N$ be a bijection.  For $r\in \mathbb R$ let $(s_r(j))_{j\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of rationals in $(r,\infty)$ that converges to $r.$ Let $T(r)=\{f(s_r(j)):j\in \mathbb N\}.$

This is to obtain a family $\{T(r):r\in \mathbb R\}$ of infinite subsets of  $\mathbb N$ such that $T(r_1)\cap T(r_2)$ is finite whenever $r_1\ne r_2.$

(2). We identify $\beta \mathbb N$ with the Wallman extension $w\mathbb N,$ which is the space of ultra-filters on $\mathbb N.$ For $n\in \mathbb N$ we identify the fixed ultra-filter $\{S\subset \mathbb N: n\in S\}$ with $n$ itself.   A basic open set in $\beta \mathbb N$ is $$U^*=\{f\in w\mathbb N: U\in f\}$$ for any $U\subset \mathbb N.$ Observe that   $$ U_1^*\cap U_2^* =(U_1\cap U_2)^*$$ so if $U_1\cap U_2$ is finite then $(U_1^*\cap U_2^*)\cap (w\mathbb N$  \   $\mathbb N)=\phi.$

(3).For each $T(r)$ in part (1) above choose $G(r)\in (T(r))^*$ \ $\mathbb N.$ Let $S=\{G(r): r\in \mathbb N\}\cup \mathbb N.$

(i). $\mathbb N$ is dense in $w\mathbb N,$ and $\mathbb N\subset S$, so $\mathbb N$  is dense in the subspace $S.$ So $S$ is separable.

(ii). $\mathbb N$ is discrete, hence locally compact, hence $\mathbb N$ is an open subset of $w\mathbb N.$ So $\mathbb N$ is an open subset of the subspace $S.$

(iii). $( T(r))^*$ is a nbhd of $G(r)$ in $w\mathbb N$ that does not contain $G(r')$ for any $r'\ne r.$  So in $S$ the set $A=\{G(r):r\in \mathbb R\}$ is a discrete subspace of $S$. And by (ii),  $A$ is closed in $S.$

(4). A separable space $S$ with a closed discrete subspace $A$, where the cardinal of $A$ is the cardinal of $R,$ cannot be a normal space.

Comment: Aha, he uses a MAD family to violate ccc in a maximal way,and then applies Jones' Lemma. Almost all ZFC proofs of non-normality involve Jones' lemma it seems, except those in ordinals spaces, like Tychonoff's plank.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. The family $\{T(r)\}_r$ need not be a maximal  AD family. You could remove some of its members. But in ZFC  it must  have cardinal $c$ to guarantee that its power set has cardinal greater than $c$....I wasn't going to post this until  the OP said (s)he said (s)he was (only) familiar with $\beta \mathbb N$ as the space of ultra-filters.

Comment: I really meant to say of maximal size $\mathfrak{c}$, you're quite right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. A normal space  $S$ is  hereditarily normal iff any two separated subsets $A,B$ of $S$ (i.e. $\bar A \cap B=A\cap \bar B=\phi$) can be completely separated. I wonder whether we could explicitly find a counter-example  in $\beta N.$

Comment: It's also equivalent to every open subspace is normal. Or every subspace is normal. Hence the name. A non-normal subspace $S$ has two disjoint relatively closed sets   $A$ and $B$ that cannot be separated by relatively open subsets. This $A$ and $B$ are as required. And the proof of Jones' lemma shows where to find such relatively closed sets... But presumably you want explicit sets, I'm not sure whether that is easy to do.

Comment: Lemma 1 in the linked paper in my answer constructs such sets from a Hausdorff gap (which are made by transfinite recursion, so not really "explicit" either); come to think of it, your worked out example from an AD family is also not fully constructive.